# How can I use For loops to reduce the number of lines in the following code?

Tags: java, android, loops

I am trying to populate a list with data from SQLite.How can I use For loops to reduce the number of lines in the following code? I will have to pass String Arrays fa, fe, fi, fo to the ListAdapter.

```
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor res = myhelp.getAllData();

    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        while (res.moveToNext()) {

            arrayList.add(res.getString(0));
            fa = arrayList.toArray(new String[0]);

            }
        }
    arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor res1 = myhelp.getAllData();

        while (res1.moveToNext()) {

            arrayList1.add(res1.getString(1));
            fe = arrayList1.toArray(new String[0]);


    }
    arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor res2 = myhelp.getAllData();

        while (res2.moveToNext()) {

            arrayList2.add(res2.getString(2));
            fi = arrayList2.toArray(new String[0]);


    }
    arrayList3 = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor res3 = myhelp.getAllData();

        while (res3.moveToNext()) {

            arrayList3.add(res3.getString(3));
            fo = arrayList3.toArray(new String[0]);

        }
```

Comment: I just hope those aren't real names of variables and you've just put them in there for SO. If they are real, please, change them.

Comment: @Amongalen Yes they aren't real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your source data is always the same you do not need to re-read it many times, and can just loop once

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
// etc
Cursor res = myhelp.getAllData();
while (res.moveToNext()) {

        arrayList.add(res.getString(0));
        fa = arrayList.toArray(new String[0]);
        arrayList1.add(res.getString(1));
        fe = arrayList1.toArray(new String[0]);
        arrayList2.add(res.getString(2));
        fi = arrayList2.toArray(new String[0]);
        // etc

}
```

**Note**

not sure what `fa = arrayList.toArray(new String[0]);` is doing but I think you can do it after the loop